# Child of a child of a First person camera not moving with camera on Y-Axis - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Now this may seem confusing but in Unity im following a 2 year old tutorial... So some stuff is different back then, and its a FPS Tutorial, and theres a empty object called bullet spawn(The point where the bullet of the gun spawns) that you put at the end of the gun, and it spawns the bullet, now i can get to that point where it spawns the bullet but When i move my camera on the Y-axis the bullet spawn doesnt move with the camera, BUT it moves with the X-Axis, How can i fix this to where it moves with the Y-Axis

Answer (score 0):

make sure you make it child of the camera and then reset its position , if it still doesnt move in y axis then i think you have written some code that is making the spawn object not move in y axis or one last thing if you have added a rigidbody component on it make sure you have not ticked the freeze rotation or direction of y axis

Hope it helps

Thank you